# Infinite loop in C, what is wrong?

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop

I am having problems with the following code in different methods.
When i run my code and enter 2 as my parameter, i get an infinite loop of zero's and ones.
I'm not sure what is wrong with that section. 
Any help would be great. Thank you!

```
/*global variables*/
int CPI[];
int Count[];
```

Whenever i choose 1 as my parameter, i enter 3 as my instruction classes however i am unable to input the CPI of class 3 or even the instruction count of class 3. Once i input the CPI and instruction count of class 2 it ends.

```
void SelectOne(){
  tot = 0;
  printf("\n Enter the number of instruction classes: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  printf("\n Enter the frequency of the machine (MHz): ");
  scanf("%d", &f);

  int CPI[n];
  int Count[n];

  int a;
  for(a = 1; a < n; a++){

    /*printf("%d",n);*/

     printf(" Enter CPI of class %d : ", a);
     scanf("%d", &CPI[a-1]);

     printf(" Enter instruction count of class %d : ", a);
     scanf("%d", &Count[a-1]);
     tot =+ Count[a-1];

  }

}
```

This is the method in which i get an infinite loop of 0's and 1's.

```
void SelectTwo(){

  printf("\n ---------------------------");
  printf("\n +Class/t + CPI/t +Count +");

  int a;
  for(a = 1; a <= n; a++){
     printf("\n %d\t + %d\t + %d ", a, CPI[a-1], Count[a-1]);

  }


}
```

I believe my problem is in main but i'm not sure of how to fix this.

```
int main(){

  int sel = 1;

  while(sel != 4){
     printf("\n 1) Enter Parameters ");
     printf("\n 2) Print table of parameters ");
     printf("\n 3) Print table of performance ");
     printf("\n 4) Quit");

     printf("\n \n Enter Selection: ");
     scanf("%d", &sel);

     if(sel == 1){
        SelectOne();
     }
     if(sel == 2){
        SelectTwo();
     }
     if(sel == 3){
        SelectThree();
     }
     else{
        printf("quit");
     }


  }

}
```

Comment: Too much code. Try to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This looks like it's probably wrong, but not causing your loop: `tot =+ Count[a-1];` (there's no `=+` operator in C). There are several other typographical errors in your posted code. If you are copying it in by hand, you might want to try just copy/paste. The `selectTwo()` function doesn't look like it could go into an infinite loop. Perhaps it's just a very long loop. Check the value of `n` when you enter the function.

Comment: How does this even compile? You define `int CPI[n]` in `SelectOne()`, and then try to access it in a completely different function, `SelectTwo()`. There's definitely something you're not telling everyone, here.

Comment: @lurker When i print n it returns the value it should be, which is the value of the instruction class that is inputted when ran.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I have both `int CPI[]` and `int Count[]` as global variables. When i compile it gives warning of the array containing one element.

Comment: @Csci01: Well, `SelectOne()` isn't using your global variables, then, because you're hiding them when you declare locals of the same name. The `CPI` and `Count` arrays that `SelectOne()` writes to get destroyed when that function exits.

Comment: @Csci01: You need to include in your question the definitions of your global variables. Since variable length arrays can only be defined in function scope, there's a real good chance your global definitions of these arrays are troublesome, given what you're trying to do in `SelectOne()`.

Comment: What's `n`? Where's `n` declared?

Comment: @Csci01: When you define a global array without ever specifying its size, the size defaults to 1. This is why you get the warning about your global `CPI` and global `Count` having size 1.

Comment: This code should not even compile. The top most global variables are 
declared wrongly, int CPI[] and int count[].
You must either initialize the arrays or provide their sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Whenever i choose 1 as my parameter, i enter 3 as my instruction classes however i am unable to input the CPI of class 3 or even the instruction count of class 3. Once i input the CPI and instruction count of class 2 it ends."

This is because you tell it to. Here:

```
for(a = 1; a < n; a++){
```

if you enter `3`, then the loop runs once when `a == 1`, a second time when `a == 2`, and then quits, because `a < 3` is no longer true. You want this:

```
for( a = 0; a < n; a++ ){      /*  Change a = 1 to a = 0  */
    printf(" Enter CPI of class %d : ", a + 1);
    scanf("%d", &CPI[a]);      /*  Change [a-1] to [a]  */

    printf(" Enter instruction count of class %d : ", a + 1);
    scanf("%d", &Count[a]);    /*  Change [a-1] to [a]  */
    tot += Count[a];           /*  Change =+ to += and [a-1] to [a]  */
}
```

Your code has lots of other problems, though, including the fact that the global variables `CPI` and `Count` that `SelectTwo()` appear to be using are not the same ones that `SelectOne()` is writing to, because in `SelectOne()` you create local variables of the same name which hide them.

EDIT: You edited your question to show the definitions of your global arrays:

```
int CPI[];
int Count[];
```

What this is actually doing is declaring an incomplete type, because you're not providing a size. Once you get to the end of the translation unit, if the array still has an incomplete type, then it's assumed to have one element, which is here set to zero on program startup. So you're effectively creating one-element arrays, so attempting to loop over more than one element in `SelectTwo()` is just undefined and nonsensical behavior.

As mentioned, the `CPI` and `Count` that `SelectOne()` is using are not the same ones that you are defining globally, so `SelectTwo()` is not reading from what `SelectOne()` is writing to.

If you want to use global arrays like this, you have to provide a size, e.g.

```
int CPI[3];
int Count[3];
```

If you don't want to provide a size (for instance, because here you want the user to choose the size), then you'll have to either use `malloc()` or define a variable length array within a function and pass it to the functions that need it.